# uncheck the checkbox for overwriting a document by default in sharepoint 2013

Tags: elements-xml, delegate-control

We are trying to remove the checkbox which appears when uploading a new document in SharePoint (we are using 2013).

By default this is checked.
We would like it to be unchecked by default.

I have seen information on how to do this by modifying the upload.aspx and uploadex.aspx file (e.g. here: http://lazysharepointadmin.com/blog/2011/08/25/change-overwrite-existing-files-behavior/#comment-111 )

However, I believe the above is not recommended (as it could cause problems when upgrading).

I've also seen brief information on how to do this via an elements.xml file and using a delegate control..?
But I don't fully understand where or how to do this and don't want to get things wrong on a master page.

Can anyone shed any light on how the AdditionalPageHead delegate control can be used to do this please?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply modify your system master page and add some javascript to the **bottom** of the page just above PlaceHolderFormDigest to set the "Overwrite existing files" checkbox to default to **Unchecked**.

http://planet-sharepoint.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/sharepoint-2010-set-overwrite-existing.html

Comment: Never modify the OOTB master page, create a copy and use it for your sites!

Answer (score 0):

**Never** modify the out of the box layouts files!

As you said, we can use `AdditionalPageHead` delegate control with jQuery/Javascript that can  uncheck the check-box by default, [see the example with delegate control](http://vegardstromsoy.blogspot.se/2011/05/jquery-to-override-sharepoint-ootb.html).